# echo $ along with variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, quoting

Im trying to do print last directory like below

```
#!/bin/bash
dirc="/a/b/"
i=3  
`echo "$dirc" | awk -F / '{ print ""$"i"}'`
```

which should print 'b', which is not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` in the AWK script is an AWK variable, not a shell variable; you need to set the AWK variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
dirc="/a/b/"
echo "${dirc}" | awk -F / -v i=3 '{print $i}'
```

You can specify the value of `i` in any way the shell understands:

```
i=3
echo "${dirc}" | awk -F / -v "i=${i}" '{print $i}'
```

You *could* also get the shell to evaluate the variable in the AWK script, but that’s just looking for trouble:

```
i=3
echo "${dirc}" | awk -F / "{print \$${i}}"
```

Comment: I am borrowing value of i else where, to simplify here I hard coded. how do I call 'i' then?

Comment: echo "${dirc}" | awk -F / -v j=$i '{print $j}'

Answer (score 2):

You could use the shell's [string operations](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to get the last part of the directory without invoking an external utility:

```
dirc="/a/b/"
dirc=${dirc%/}         # remove trailing / if it is there
echo "${dirc##*/}"     # remove everything up to the last /
```

Which outputs `b`. Note that this will not work if `dirc` is just `/`, so `basename` may be better.

Or get one field by number, through a [shell array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html).

```
IFS=/ read -a dira <<< "$dirc"   # split to an array
echo "${dira[2]}"                # echo one field, first is 0
```

---

As an aside, surely the backticks in your `echo | awk` command are a typo? With them, the shell would take the output from awk as a command to run.

Comment: Good catch with the backticks. I didn't spot that.

Answer (score 1):

To print the last part of the path, use `basename`:

```
$ dirc='/a/b/'
$ basename "$dirc"
b
```

To get the ith `/`-delimited field using `awk`, set an `awk` variable, `var` for example, to the value of `$i`, then use `$var` in `awk` to access the ith field:

```
$ i=3
$ echo "$dirc" | awk -v var="$i" -F '/' '{ print $var }'
b
```

The difference between `var` and `$var` in `awk` is that `var` is a numeric value (in this instance) while `$var` is the value of the field corresponding to that numeric value.

---

As ilkkachu noted, the backticks around the last line in your code does not make sense. It will cause the result of the command (the string `b`) to be interpreted as a command which will be executed.